# Where are I/O schedulers set permanently? Kubuntu 20.04.1 64 bit

Tags: kernel, disk-usage, system, scheduler

I want to use two schedulers since I have a two Disks set for my system due to a separate HOME disk. Meaning I have SDA and SDB

Doing  `echo noop /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` says permission denied with SUDO

I tried the suggested solution but it doesn't work anymore

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/60-schedulers.rules
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sda", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="noop"
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="nvme0n1", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="noop"
cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler 
[none] mq-deadline
```

The setting is to be system-wide

It could be like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash elevator:sda=noop elevator:nvme0n1=noop"
```

Is this the correct line or do I need a comma between the two disk parameters?

Comment: While not ideal, you could schedule that command in rc.local or with systemd to run on startup. The link below refers to upstart, which I believe is outdated but related. http://askubuntu.com/a/910/647604

Comment: There's [a Debian Wiki entry that describes one method](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization#Low-Latency_IO-Scheduler): `sudo -i` followed by `apt install sysfsutils` followed by `echo "block/sda/queue/scheduler = noop" >> /etc/sysfs.conf`. That line might be wrong and need to be removed and then replaced using `none` instead of `noop`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex How do I get this command's man page ?

Comment: There's no real command or man page for the file. The contents of `/etc/sysfs.conf` after you install the package have a bit of an explanation of it, though.

Comment: @userDepth - Deleted the answer as requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use udev rule for that.

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/60-schedulers.rules

ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sda", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="deadline"
```

Comment: I think Noop is no longer available in Ubuntu

Comment: Now it's "none" instead of noop for SSD's